# GNU autoconf, document options using doxygen?

Tags: documentation, doxygen, autotools, autoconf

Is it possible to document configure.ac such that doxygen can pick up embedded comments and produce documentation for options, variables, etc. in generated manuals?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should comment using Doxygen using comments like *##!*, right? I don't think that Doxygen supports comments like that, but you could try to modify Doxygen to accept comments like that, then you can document using usual Doxygen commands *@var*, *@cond*, etc.

The modification could be hard, but you can try to modify this file [commentcnv.l](http://doxygen.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/doxygen/trunk/src/commentcnv.l?revision=717&view=markup) (starting from @line 319). Maybe you can mail with project developer mailing list.

Comment: actually python documentation uses double hash, maybe I can trick doxygen into treating configure.ac as python/Perl file.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are contributed Autoconf macros for Doxygen at the [Autoconf Archive](http://www.nongnu.org/autoconf-archive/ax_prog_doxygen.html#ax_prog_doxygen). Include the `DX_INIT_DOXYGEN` macro in `configure.ac` and then automake will create targets such as `doxygen-doc` for generating various subsets of the documentation.

Comment: thanks, however I need to document configure.ac itself, rather than produce doxygen-* targets

Comment: Oh. Then I don't know, sorry.